# How to call a function another function as a parameter passed as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service function I'm trying to call in the controller. That service also calls another function in the same service. When I can call the service from the controller, I can only get it to work if I explicitly pass in the 2nd service. What I would like to do is be able to pass a string that calls the 2nd service instead. It looks cleaner and easier to read. But I can't figure out how to this.

**Service:**

```
function $cmCallOut($timeout, $cmAutoscroll) {

    var service = {
      runCallOut: runCallOut,
      unavailable: unavailable,
      destroy: destroy,
      create: create,
      update: update
    };
    return service;

    function runCallOut(recordId, callout) {
      // Wrap in timeout to wait for DOM to load before grabbing the element
      $timeout(function() {
        // Get element which to perform callout animation on
        var element = angular.element('[record-id=' + recordId + ']');
        // Get the elements coords so we can scroll to it
        var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        // Scroll to element
        $cmAutoscroll.toTop(rect.top);
        // Run animation
        callout(element);
      });
    }

    function unavailable(element) {
      element.velocity('callout.shake');
    }

    function destroy(element) {
      element.velocity('transition.expandOut', {duration : 350});
    }

    function create(element) {
      element.css('display', 'none');
      element
      .velocity('transition.expandIn', {duration : 450, display: 'block', delay: 350})
      .velocity('callout.flash');
      $timeout(function() {
        element.css('transform', 'none');
      }, 2000);
    }

    function update(element) {
      element.velocity('callout.flash', {duration: 1500, delay: 350});
    }

  }
```

**Controller:**

```
$cmCallOut.runCallOut(chargeId, $cmCallOut.create);
```

**Want to call it like this:**

```
$cmCallOut.runCallOut(chargeId, 'create');
```

Comment: What about an associative array `var func = { create: $cmCallOut.create }; $cmCallOut.runCallOut(chargeId, func['create']);`

Comment: need to inject second service in the first and remove that injection from controller

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass a string for the second parameter and decide which function to call according to that string. In this  case, you may use 'switch' and add the different cases you have and call the appropriate function according to sent parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function you want is a key on the service variable you declared on top, you can invoke it like this:

```
service[callout](element);
```

So...

```
function runCallOut(recordId, callout) {
  // Wrap in timeout to wait for DOM to load before grabbing the element
  $timeout(function() {
    // Get element which to perform callout animation on
    var element = angular.element('[record-id=' + recordId + ']');
    // Get the elements coords so we can scroll to it
    var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    // Scroll to element
    $cmAutoscroll.toTop(rect.top);
    // Run by calling the function that is a key on service
    service[callout](element);
  });
}
```